# do we really need ' def ' ? (python syntax-improvement offer)

Tags: python

JavaScript `var x = 10` is the same as `x = 10` in Python. A little bit simpler. But in Python why do we use

```
def f(x): x+1
f(0)           # => 1
```

instead of

```
f(x): x+1
f(0)           # => 1
```

Isn't the second one better? Anyway , inspired by The Zen of Python, my questions are:

1. What are the (potential) obstacles which could make the second pattern impossible to work? Can you give some code examples?
2. If there are no problems with the second pattern, can Python designers change it if someone informs them?

Comment: Do you remove `class`, too? How do you distinguish between `Class(Superclass)` and `function(parameter)`? You could consider making this a [PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/) (read "Submitting a PEP" carefully).

Comment: yep, i thought about that. we can keep `class Class(Super): ....` .  there is no problem if defining class like this. or we can make `Class: inherit(Super) ....`

Comment: I think def adds a certain amount of readability to the code. When you have lines and lines of code it acts as a visual marker. If it ain't broke don't fix it!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about a specific programming problem.

Comment: I think the consistency in definition is more important than saving the few keystrokes, in this instance. If functions don't need 'def' but classes need 'class', we lose some of the predictability, and as pointed out, we can't remove 'class' as well, otherwise there's confusion.

Comment: @user2963623 the OP's proposed "new" code is difficult to read partly because they are using (not recommended) one-line functions. With a multi-line function the indentation would still show the structure.

Comment: @SimonFraser i agree, it is a small matter. actually the same inconsistency already exists between variable and function declaration. that's why i used js example. all i lean on is - beginner eye that searches for as much simplicity and shortness as possible :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Even if they are multiline functions, the function names will all be different. So there won't be a standard identifier to distinguish all functions. In the event of just skimming the codes, it might become difficult to point out functions, unless the editor has some garish color for function names. This would make reading codes in notepad really difficult!!

Comment: @user2963623 that is true (not that reading code in notepad isn't difficult enough already!)

Comment: Well, when it comes down to it, notepad opens up the fastest! :P

Answer (score 2):

Python's syntax is not trying to be the most minimal grammar that is unambiguous for a computer to parse.  It's trying to be a readable syntax for people.  A function definition is a significant event in a program.  It deserves a keyword.

You say, "beginner eye that searches for as much simplicity and shortness as possible."  I disagree that beginners want things to be as short as possible.  They want things to be as readable as possible. This requires a balance.

As another example, we could probably drop the colon at the ends of lines, as CoffeeScript does.  But the colon is a good indicator of the expectation of an indented clause, and is a nice compromise between pure minimalism (CoffeeScript) and over-punctuating (C++).

Comment: +1. Per [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) (emphasis mine): *'One of Guido's key insights is that **code is read much more often than it is written**... As PEP 20 says, "Readability counts"'*.

Answer (score 0):

Expect a lot of inane rebuttals. People don't like change. The reality is, your suggested change is completely valid and if Python had originally been designed that way, no one would question it now.

I hate `def` too. I think it is ugly and redundant. The colon and indentation are enough to disambiguate a function definition from a function call as well as establish readability.

Also, the `class` keyword distinguishes it from classes. It also makes sense for `class` to require the keyword and functions not to because functions are more common than classes.

That said, your post is more appropriate for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ than https://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: Classy move: "inane rebuttals" :)

Comment: I'm not saying every possible rebuttal will be inane. Someone could give a well-reasoned rebuttal. But from my experience suggesting new ideas that challenge the status quo: most of them probably will be. "inane": empty, devoid of meaningful content. Just a rationalization of their emotional distaste for change.

Answer (score 0):

I agree user2963623 that `def` adds slight readability.

For variable definition/assignment, `var` is worth to remove because it appears more often than function definition, and `=` is a good syntax for definition/assignment (natural and short).

Unlike `=`, `:` has some other usages. I can think of some situations that removing `def` causes a little confusing (probably mainly to python interpreter):

1. `a_list_or_tuple[f(x): x]`
2. `if f(x): blabla`

Of course we can create rules to define these two cases are not function definition. But to me, it's unnecessary, just use `def` is clearer and simple enough.

Comment: i dont think someone defines a function inside if clause or tuple, so dont think it might cause a problem. but agree about a little confusion.

Comment: as I edited, the confusion is mainly to python interpreter. It's quite possible we call a function in tuple/list indexing and if/while clause. Then it requires additional work for interpreter to distinguish. And for the language itself, in order to make function definition without any ambiguity, the description would be more complicated (compared with `def`)